# How can I fix the missing bottom part in React Native Modal displaying on Android mobile devices?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, modal-dialog, dimension

In React Native, I have an Image in Modal.

However, when the Modal is first displayed, it encounters an error where the bottom part is missing.

[This bug when Modal show in first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4jly.jpg)

When I try to do close Modal and turn it back on, it works fine again with full screen rendering.

[When I close and reopen modal again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3OxF.jpg)

I tried using Dimensions (width, height)and flex but not working for my case.

What happened and how can i fix this. Please help me.

- Node version: 18
- React Native version: 0.71
- Devices: Redmi note 8 pro, Samsung Galaxy note 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue like a week ago.
Couldn't fix it easily.

I've "fixed" it by doing a full screen with my component and `react-navigation`

Comment: Please tell me in more detail how you did to "fix" it